# angularjs not using $rootscope and $broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

So basically I'm trying to find a way to prevent using $rootscope ,$broadcast and $apply. Let me show you the code first:

```
         app.controller('firstController', function ($scope, ServiceChatBuddy, socketListeners){ 

            $scope.ChatBuddy = ServiceChatBuddy;
            $scope.$on('user delete:updated', function (event, id) {
                $scope.ChatBuddy.users[id]['marker'].setMap(null);
                delete $scope.ChatBuddy.users[id];
            });
            $scope.$on('loadPosition:updated', function (event, data) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.ChatBuddy.users[data.id] = data.obj;
                });
             // and a bunch more like these
            });
          })
```

the socketListeners is a 3rd party libary (socket.io )which I implemented in a factory which will broadcast data when an event has occured

```
      socketModule.factory('socketListeners', function ($rootScope, decorateFactory) {
          var sockets = {};
          var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
          sockets.listen = function () {
                socket.on('loadPosition', function (data) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('loadPosition:updated', data)
            });
            socket.on('client leave', function (id) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('user delete:updated', id);
            });
            // and a bunch more of these
       });
```

As you can see the code exist alot of $rootscope $broadcasts and $apply;

So I'm struggling to find a way to do this more 'professional'. Any hints tricks best practices are absolutely welcome! cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

socket.js (service)

```
angular.module('app')
.service('socket', function (socketFactory) {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

    var mySocket = socketFactory({
        ioSocket: socket
    });

    return mySocket;
});
```

firstController.js

```
app.controller('firstController', function ($scope, socket){

    socket.forward('user delete:updated', $scope);
    socket.forward('loadPosition:updated', $scope);

    $scope.$on('user delete:updated', function (event, id) {
        $scope.ChatBuddy.users[id]['marker'].setMap(null);
        delete $scope.ChatBuddy.users[id];
    });
    $scope.$on('loadPosition:updated', function (event, data) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.ChatBuddy.users[data.id] = data.obj;
        });
        // and a bunch more like these
    });
});
```

when scope is destroyed, listeners are destroyed too :)